# Questions on unitary infinite representation of topological and Lie Groups

Tags: functional-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras, adjoint-operators

Let $G$ a topological group, $H$ a complex Hilbert space and $U(H)$ the group of unitary operators. A unitary group representation is a group homomorphism $\phi:G\longrightarrow U(H)$ continuos respect the strong operator topology. $\phi$ is continuos if only if the induced action $G\curvearrowright H$ is continuos.

**Q1:** Why the strong operator topology is the right topology for the definition? (Instead of the weak operator topology, the norm topology or the compact-open). If moreover $G$ is a Lie group, we could restrict to $\phi$ such that the action $G\curvearrowright H$ is smooth. What implies this restriction?

I read that the continuos (with SOT) group homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R \longrightarrow U(H)$ are in bijection with densely defined skew-selfadjoint operators $A$ in $H$. In particular we can define the exponential map
$ \exp(A):=V(1)$.

Every $\phi:G \longrightarrow U(H)$ unitary representation of a Lie group induce the "differential" map $d\phi:Lie(G) \longrightarrow \mathcal S(H)$, with range $\mathcal S(H)$ the densely defined skew-selfadjoint operators in $H$, defined by:
$$ \phi(e^{tX})=\exp(td\phi(X)) $$

**Q2.1:** $\mathcal S(H)$ forms a Lie algebra with the brackets $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. Is it true that $d\phi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism?

**Q2.2:** If $G$ is a simply-connected Lie group, does every Lie algebra homomorphism $d\phi:Lie(G) \longrightarrow \mathcal S(H)$ come from the differential of a unitary representation? What can we say if we change the topology in $U(H)$ or if we restrict to smooth (unitary) actions $G\curvearrowright H$?

**Q3:** Are there any good reference for these questions and more topics on group representations?

Comment: Surely you want everything to be smooth because you want compatibility with the Lie group structure. We do not use the norm topology because many interesting representations are not norm-continuous, though they are strong continuous. On the other hand, I guess (but I'm no expert here) that allowing the weak topology would allow too many representations.

Comment: Yes, I think that maybe the conjecture in Q2.2 isn't true in other topologies. I think if we change to the norm topology, $d\phi(X)$ is necessarily a bounded operator (and restricts too much). Maybe the continuos action $G\curvearrowright H$ induced by an unitary group representation of a Lie group is always smooth.

Comment: When dealing with unbounded operators, you really have to be careful with the domains. For example, the commutator of skew-selfadjoint operators is in general not skew-selfadjoint or even only densely defined.

Comment: @Quantum, The weak operator topology coincides with the strong operator topology on the unitary group.

Comment: @Ruy You are right. My remark still applies when working with non-unitary representations though.

Comment: @MaoWao I thought that $\mathcal S(H)$ form a Lie algebra. But in some cases we do a similar path. The representation of the Heisenberg algebra $d\rho(p,q,t)=i2\pi(pX+qD+t)$,  $(Xf)(x)=xf(x)$, $Df(x)=-i/2\pi f'(x)$ induce the representation of the Heisenberg Lie Group $\rho(p,q,t)=\exp(i2\pi (pX+qD+t))$. Maybe if $\phi$ is a Lie group unitary representation, $d\phi(Lie(G))\subset \mathcal S(H) $ is a Lie algebra?

Comment: @Ruy I didn't know, where can I read the proof?

Comment: I'm reading that these questions are partially answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139973/representation-of-lie-groups-as-exponentiations-of-algebra-representations?rq=1. But I can't find on internet the theorems of Garding and Nelson that he mentioned.

Comment: Try I.3.2.9 in "Operator Algebras" by Blackadar.

Comment: Regarding Q1 you might want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885933/definition-of-finite-dimensional-representation-of-a-compact-group/3887800#3887800